# Vbulletin 3.8.7 and PHP 5.2.17 Concerns

Tags: php, security, vbulletin

My friend was wondering if there were any security concerns when running vbulletin 3.8.7 and PHP 5.2.17 on CentOS. I saw that PHP 5.2.17 was vulnerable to CVE-2012-2688 and CVE-2012-2386, but I do not know if vbulletin utilizes the Phar extension or the scandir() function that accepts user input. Can anyone familiar with vbulletin's source tell me if my friend should be concerned over these vulnerabilites?

Answer (score 0):

While what vB does is a question more suitable to the official vB forums, we can easily check the status of any CVE in CentOS.

CentOS is a derivative of Red Hat Enterprise Linux.  Any CVEs acted upon by RHEL will make their way into CentOS within a few weeks.

- [CVE-2012-2386](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2012-2386) was rated "moderate" severity by RHEL.  It was patched in the `php53` packages for RHEL5 and the `php` packages for RHEL6.  The `php` package in vanilla RHEL5 is 5.1 was not updated, as you can't do PHARs in 5.1.
- [CVE-2012-2688](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2012-2688) has been rated "low" severity by RHEL and *has not been patched*.  I tried following the CVE links, but they all ended in a severe lack of useful information about what the exploit is and how to trigger it.  It all leads back to the PHP changelog, which simply lists that there was a bug and it was fixed, without listing the bug number.

However, there's a big fat glaring problem.

- RHEL 5 shipped with PHP 5.1, and offers PHP 5.3 as a separate package.
- RHEL 6 shipped with PHP 5.3.

You are running PHP 5.2.  **No RHEL or CentOS release has *ever* offered 5.2**.  You got those RPMs from an external source, and therefore need to check with *that* source to see if they have backported changes.  Assume that they have not.

Consider using [Remi's repo](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en) for PHP updates.  Remi is the PHP package manager for the Fedora distro, the upstream source of the distro that eventually becomes RHEL.